# Changing the <mark> tags' color through internal CSS

Tags: html, css

```
    .myDiv {
    border: 2px solid slategray;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
mark {
    background-color:darkgray;
    color:black;
}
```

}

This is my current CSS, which does not work. I'm trying to figure out how to change the <mark> tags' color scheme, but i only want it done within my ".myDiv" class.

Do i have to put it in its' own class or does it just need alittle changing?

tried including it within the class's brackets without making brackets for the mark tag itself, but that didn't work either.

Comment: where is your clsing `}` for `.myDiv`

Comment: try `.myDiv mark { /*styles*/ }` - *but i only want it done within my ".myDiv" class.*

Comment: @Mysticizmo, no, `.myDiv mark` - since it is just heredity.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov   
Ahh yes, understood it once in code (as below). Thought you meant adding the "mark" in the parent .myDiv :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it as following

```css
  .myDiv {
    border: 2px solid slategray;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.myDiv mark {
    background-color:darkgray;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="myDiv">
   bla bla bla <mark>marked text</mark> bla bla
</div>


<mark>not effected outside myDiv<mark>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* create a class of `<mark>` especially for `myDiv`. Eg:

```
.myDiv_mark{
  background-color:darkgray;
  color:black
```

Comment: Doesn't this make it so that i have to include an extra class in my div? instead of using just ".myDiv" i also have to use ".myDiv_mark" ?

Comment: yes, unfortunately - you're completely right. just after i posted this answer, i saw the other answer, that one is better.